# How to switch digits validator by function in jQuery validation plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

On jQuery site [Plugins/Validation/Methods/digits](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/digits)
there is example:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      digits: true
    }
  }
});
```

I would like to decide if validation needed by function.
I have a problem only for **digits** specifically when I try next:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      digits: function() { return false; }
    }
  }
});
```

Validation plugin still require digits only for my input field.
How to switch **digits** validator by function in jQuery validate plugin?

Comment: what do you mean by when i try next ????

Comment: I would like to decide if validation needed by function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need

```
digits: {
depends: function(){
      return false;                            
   }
}
```

try this

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
          digits: {
         depends: function(){
                 return (some_condition());
             }
         }
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: I would like to decide if validation needed by function.

Comment: you are welcome :D, if this is the correct answer , please marklit as the correct answer .

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but just in case if you permanently want to replace the default 'required' functionality - you can do like this -

```
 $.validator.addMethod("required", function(value, element, param) {
    // your logic here

    // return the result
    return false;
  }, "custom message" /* or the default message - jQuery.validator.messages.required */
  );
```